# WPF - Use default value from style if property in view model is null

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have own custom control with dependency property called Maximum (double) and I have defined own style for this custom control. In custom control style is setter for Maximum (50). In application I have view model with property Maximum (double?).

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomControlDefaultStyle" TargetType="controls:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="50" />

</Style>
<controls:MyControl Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" 
                                Style="{StaticResource MyCustomControlDefaultStyle}" 
                                       />
```

If Maximum value in view model will be null I want to wpf automatically use default value defined in MyCustomControlDefaultStyle. Is it possible?
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't check right now, but you could put your DefaultValue inside a static Property and then reference this value from the style and from the Fallbackvalue/TargetNullValue inside the concrete Binding like:

```
<Setter Property="Maximum" Value="{x:Static ns:MyStaticClass.MyStaticProp}" />
```

And inside the Binding like:

```
<controls:MyControl Maximum="{Binding Maximum, FallBackValue={x:Static ns:MyStaticClass.MyStaticProp}" 
                                Style="{StaticResource MyCustomControlDefaultStyle}"  />
```

Not sure if that works for FallBackValue. I will check a little later... :)

Comment: It was my idea too, but it would be nice do not apply binding if value in view model is null and use value from style :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DataTrigger` in your style along with a `Converter`:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Maximum, Converter={StaticResource NullToBooleanConverter}}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Maximum}" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The converter may look like this:

```
class NullToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Edit: Can't manage the syntax highlight to work...